# Plugin dont find the MongoDB Classes

Tags: java, mongodb, minecraft, spigot

I code a plugin with MongoDB and added the libaries with Maven

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Well the I think the libaries have to be in the Jar-File. But there is no mongodb libarie[image]

Everytime when i start the server this crash blow up.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/client/MongoClients
        at me.moritz.mysql.MongoProvider.connect(MongoProvider.java:12) ~[?:?]
        at me.moritz.Main.onEnable(Main.java:36) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:370) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:500) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:518) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:432) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:965) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:726) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:54) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:159) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:826) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:788) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.handleCommandQueue(DedicatedServer.java:470) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:437) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1347) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1135) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:291) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.client.MongoClients
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:155) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:114) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-790]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519) ~[?:?]
        ... 19 more
```

I search for the problem since more than 3 days. I'm at the end of my knowledge.
I tried class path options, install maven shade plugin idk

Comment: Are you well using the `MyPlugin-with-dependencies.jar` file ? Also, does it works with `maven deploy` command ?

Comment: I thought when i download it in Maven it will work. How can i use it?

Answer (score -1):

Server don't find that class because it doesn't exist, you build your plugin wrong.

Try to build your plugin using build artifact.

**IntelliJ IDEA**

**Ctrl + Alt + Shift + s** → **Artifacts** → **JAR** → **From modules with dependencies *(don't enter Main class)*** → **Ok** *and then*  ***(On taskbar)* Build** → **Build artifact** → ***(your artifact name)* Build**

If you use Eclipse (or others) I can't help you.